Why is gitlab pages not working with directories?
I'm trying to deploy static pages with gitlab ci, and create a directory for each branch and commit. Similar to Gitlab pages - Incremental deploy But when I try to look at the branch it gives me a 404.
My gitlab ci look something like this:
image: busybox
pages:
  script:
    - echo "public/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME, public/$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"
    - mkdir -p "public/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" "public/$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"
    - cp web/* "public/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME/"
    - cp web/* "public/$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA/"
    - cp test.html public/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public

I have tried:

exmpl.co/[commit hash]/
exmpl.co/[commit hash]/index.html
exmpl.co/[branch]/
exmpl.co/[branch]/index.html

without success. I added test.html to the root of server, and it is accessible.
